# java-similar methods in the same class

Tags: java, class, methods, private

I am studying an example program. Basically it registers a customer to a type of service, and using the method below, we can pull out the customer numbers under a certain type of service.

My question is that,  what's the purpose of designing it this way? I reckon the user calls the first method, and first method calls the second one? Also are we allowed to have methods with the same name in one class? Thanks!

```
public ArrayList<Integer> listCustomerNumber(String Service) {
    return listCustomer(service, thisYear, thisMonth);
}

ArrayList<Integer> listCustomerNumber(String serviceName, int year, int month) {
    ArrayList <Integer> ids = new ArrayList <Integer> ();
    Services sd = findServices(serviceName, year, month);
    if (sd != null){
        ArrayList <Customer> customers = sd.listCustomers();
        for (int i=0; i<customers.size(); ++i) {
            ids.add(customers.get(i).getId());
        }
    }
    return ids;
}
```

Comment: This is called "method overloading" and is very common. Have a read of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html and also Google "Java method overloading".

Comment: In your case, this is just an easy way to provide default values for the `year` and `month` parameters. This is usually done simply for convenience. In most cases you would probably use the current year and month, so you'd call the first method which would fill the 2 missing parameters for you.

Answer (score 1):

As @NPE said in the comment it's called [`Method Overloading`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

If it's in the same class with the equal number of parameters with the same types and order, then it is not possible for example:

```
int methoda(String a,int b) {
        return b;
}
String methoda(String b,int c) {
        return b;    
}
```

if the number of parameters and their types is same but order is different then it is possible since it results in method overloading. It means if the method signature is same which includes method name with number of parameters and their types and the order they are defined.

You should also read about [Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)